# How did classical physics explain Bremsstrahlung?

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-mechanics

What was the explanation for why electron emmits photon when it slows down from the perspective of classical physics at the time, meaning maxwell's equations?

Why isn't it the case that the kinetic energy of the electron convert to potential energy and thus energy is conserved. Why kinetic energy converted into photons?

Comment: Accelerated (or, more properly here deaccelerated) charged emit radiation. This is a classic, Maxwell-supported viewpoint.

Comment: How does maxwell's equations explain this, or at least how they are consestent with it?

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bremsstrahlung for example.

Comment: this is covered in J.D. Jackson, "Classical Electrodynamics" in detail.